# Text in android app (beginner...)

Tags: android, xml, text

My problem is very simple: I've started an app for playing Darts. The app will have several activities ('pages').

One page will be about the rules of the game. I'll be using a scroll layout because it's quite some text. But how to get the text there?!

I assume working with strings is not the best way? Do I use the XML file to get the text on screen then or does it work via Java (Assetmanager)? 
Maybe there are sample apps in which large chunks of text are used?

I know this really might seem like a trivial question but I haven't a clue where to begin.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `strings.xml` in your `res\values` folder can define strings by ID which allows easier internationalization (i18n), so that you can easily adjust the strings used in your app to locale (which is done automatically, and it falls back to `strings.xml` if it can't find a `strings-hu.xml` with Hungarian locale. You can also define `string-array` and the like in XMLs. Then all you need is a layout XML with a `ScrollView` in it that has a `TextView` in it and then you set `android:text="@string/rules"` for that TextView and you're done.

Comment: Maybe put this in an answer @epicpandaforce

Comment: `I'll be using a scroll layout because it's quite some text.` I use a Fragment which shows a WebView with an HTML file I load from the `assets` folder (depending on the current user's locale). It's scrollable and the contents are styled through a CSS. I also have expandable/collapsable divs.

Comment: @Neil yeah, I think I'll do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is so simple my friend.
You can simply use TextView and in "android:text" you refer to the string that you delared in strings.xml file (by its name)

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:text="@string/text_name"
/>
```

If your text is dynamic, you can modify it in Java code!

Answer (score 1):

You should put your string in your `strings.xml` in your `res\values` folder.

You can define strings by `ID` which allows easier internationalization (i18n), so that you can easily adjust the strings used in your app to locale (which is done automatically using `resource identifiers`, and it falls back to `strings.xml` if it can't find a `strings-hu.xml` in case you have Hungarian locale set as system language).

You can also define `string-array` and the like in XMLs. Then all you need is create a layout XML with a `ScrollView` in it that has a `TextView` in it and then you set `android:text="@string/rules"` for that TextView and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Make a String Resource like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="string1"> your text </string>
    <string name="string2"> your text </string>
</resources>
```

and access like this if you are in Activity.

```
getResources().getString(R.string.string1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are a begginer you should read some tutorials after post a question...
I give you a three nice tutorials below :

1. [Want to Learn How to Program for Android? Start Here](http://www.xda-developers.com/want-to-learn-how-to-program-for-android-start-here/)
2. [Android Programming Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/)
3. [Android Development with Android Studio or Eclipse ADT](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Android/article.html)

About your question, if you don't know how to use the `string.xml` resource just read the [string-resource guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

Hope it helps.